# Cleaning state object using wildcard in spark structured streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

We are planning to use spark structured streaming's arbitrary state processing for one of our use cases where we want to maintain certain attributes of user in the state. The query runs for a multi-tenant environment and hence we have kept the state key as `<tenantID>:<userId>`. Now, when the tenant is deleted, we want to remove the state as soon as possible.

So, what we are looking for is to delete all the state keys `<tenantId>:*`, when we receive a tenant delete event.
Is there a way we can achieve that with arbitrary state processing in spark structured streaming?